# How can we increase magnetic field strength of a magnet in physics lab?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I want to do an experiment on magnetic levitation by increasing the magnetic field strength of the bar magnet. My experiment is mainly based on the effect on the levitation distance when we increase the magnetic field strength of the bar magnet. Any simple tips for conducting this experiment?

Comment: You should add more information. At the very least, what kind of magnet are you using?

Comment: If you try diamagnetic levitation of water you need about 16 Tesla, which is about 16 times what you get from a normal bar magnet. That is unlikely to work. Pyrolytic carbon can levitate a few mm over normal neodymium magnets.